# Find Monday's date with Python

Tags: python, django

How do I find the previous Monday's date, based off of the current date using Python? I thought maybe I could use: `datetime.weekday()` to do it, but I am getting stuck.

I basically want to find today's date and Mondays date to construct a date range query in django using: `created__range=(start_date, end_date)`.

Comment: Coming Monday or past Monday?

Comment: I was looking for the past Monday

Answer (score 210, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)
datetime.date(2009, 10, 26)
```

*Some words of explanation:*

Take todays date. Subtract the number of days which already passed this week (this gets you 'last' monday). Add one week.

**Edit**: The above is for 'next monday', but since you were looking for 'last monday' you could use

```
today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
```

Comment: Python is awesome :) This is difficult and non-trivial in most other languages.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer question which was for last monday not next monday

Comment: @GeraldKaszuba actually it's much easier and more readable in PHP: `new DateTime("last monday")` or `strtotime("last monday")`.

Comment: @JustAC0der How would you get the last monday before an arbitrary date, as opposed to today?

Comment: @BallpointBen For example: `strtotime("last monday", strtotime("2018-03-14"))`, but I don't want to get into a discussion about which language is better. All languages have their drawbacks and advantages.

Comment: The accepted solution for finding last Monday might not work for all cases. Example below:

`>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> today = date(2020, 4, 6)
>>> today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
datetime.date(2020, 4, 6)
>>> `

Answer (score 60):

ChristopheD's post is close to what you want. I don't have enough rep to make a comment :(

Instead of (which actually gives you the next upcoming monday):

```
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)
datetime.date(2009, 10, 26)
```

I would say:

```
>>> last_monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
```

If you want the previous week, add the 'weeks=1' parameter.

This makes the code more readable since you are subtracting a timedelta. This clears up any confusion caused by adding a timedelta that has negative and positive offsets.

Comment: The above solution for finding last Monday might not work for all cases. Example below:

`>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> today = date(2020, 4, 6)
>>> today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
datetime.date(2020, 4, 6)
>>> `

Answer (score 26):

I think the easiest way is using [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest) like this:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, MO

today = date.today()
last_monday = today + relativedelta(weekday=MO(-1))
print last_monday
```

Answer (score 16):

Note: The OP says in the comments, "*I was looking for the past Monday*". I take this to mean we are looking for the last Monday that occurred strictly before today.

The calculation is a little difficult to get right using only the `datetime` module (especially given the above interpretation of "past Monday" and if you wish to avoid clunky `if-statements`). For example, if `today` is a Monday such as `2013-12-23`,

```
today - DT.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
```

returns `2013-12-23`, which is the same day as `today` (not the past Monday).

The advantage of using the [dateutil module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) is that you don't have to do tricky mental calculations nor force the reader to do the same to get the right date. `dateutil` does it all for you:

```
import dateutil.relativedelta as rdelta
import datetime as DT

today = DT.date(2013, 12, 23)  # Monday

past_monday = today + rdelta.relativedelta(days=-1, weekday=rdelta.MO(-1))
print(past_monday)
# 2013-12-16

next_monday = today + rdelta.relativedelta(days=1, weekday=rdelta.MO(+1))
print(next_monday)
# 2013-12-30
```

Note that `days=-1` is needed to guarantee that `past_monday` is a different day than `today`.

Comment: You are using the easy-tool the hard-way ;)

Answer (score 8):

For future googlers who show up on this page looking for a way to get "the most recent Sunday", rather than "the most recent Monday", you need to do some additional math because datetime.weekday() treats Monday as the first day of the week:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday() + 1
start_day = today - datetime.timedelta(days=weekday % 7)
```

If today is Tuesday, this sets `start_day` to last Sunday. If today is Sunday, this sets `start_day` to *today*. Take away the `% 7` if you want "last Sunday" to be a week ago if it's currently Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

Using timedeltas and datetime module:

```
import datetime
datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=-datetime.date.today().weekday())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Natty**. I tried *parsedatetime* and *dateparser*. Comparing these three, I think **Natty** is the best one.

To get your result, use like this:

```
>>> from natty import DateParser
>>> dp = DateParser('last monday')
>>> dp.result()
[datetime.datetime(2016, 8, 1, 17, 35, 5, tzinfo=tzlocal())] #Today is 9th of August 2016 5.35 PM
```

Github Link : https://github.com/eadmundo/python-natty

Try it, It can do more!

Answer (score 1):

```
d = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
```

gives you today's day of the week, counting 0 (monday) to 6 (sunday)

```
datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=(7-d)%7)
```

(7-d)%7 gives you days until Monday, or leaves you where you are if today is Monday